# IBM MobileFirst Compile in Android Studio Issue

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

I built a Multipage application by using IBM MobileFirst, according to

https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-0/client-side-development-basics/building-multi-page-application/

See the [A separate HTML file for each application “page”]

It work fine on my Open MobileFirst Console.

[image]

But When I try to run in Android Studio, as below show:

[image]

After I click Run, the simulator show blank activity.

[image]

Below is the error log from Android Studio:

[image]

Anyone know what is the reason ?? Thanks in advance.

The link is my code:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/r73giz4s7hkoh97/AAAbHvpC6TgER-pSL0Y_5rgka?dl=0

Comment: Those errors mean nothing. Provide a fuller log or your project for inspection.

Comment: Okay, will do it in 5mins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android's WebView is less forgiving than a desktop browser, I suppose.

You're trying to load `MainPage.html` but the filename is actually `mainPage.html` (note the lower-case "m"). Fix this discrepancy and the page will load correctly also when testing in Android Emulator.

---

P.S.,
As a best practice you should move the inline CSS and JS from index.html into main.css and main.js instead.